# If checkbox is checked do this else do this Not Working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to add tax if the checkbox is click or not add it, if it is not also if the checkbox is checked after the amount is added to add the tax and vice versa to remove tax if it is unchecked. My code is below but i am getting the error message of `updatetotal` is not a function. from what i have read this should work but isn't. please ignore the `$j` this is setup for non conflict jquery on the database

```
$j(function() {

        $j(document).on('keyup', '#addit_fee_cost_net', function() {  
            updateTotal();
        });
        var updateTotal = function () {
          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var total = addit_fees;
            if(isNaN(total)){
            total=0.00;
            }
        output_total.val(total.toFixed(2));
        };          

        $j(document).on('change','#addit_taxable_flag', function() { 
    if($j(this).is(":checked")) {           
            updateTotal();

        var updateTotal = function () {
          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total_inc_vat = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var tax = parseFloat($j('#tax_id').val());

        var total_inc_vat = addit_fees * (tax + 1);
            if(isNaN(total_inc_vat)){
            total_inc_vat=0.00;
            }
        output_total_inc_vat.val(total_inc_vat.toFixed(2));
        };
    } else {
            updateTotal();
                    var updateTotal = function () {
          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var total = addit_fees;
            if(isNaN(total)){
            total=0.00;
            }
        output_total.val(total.toFixed(2));
        };  
    }
    });
});
```

I have just added the below answers so i am now not getting the undifined error but the if checked isnt working so nothing alters on change.

$j(function() {

```
        $j(document).on('keyup', '#addit_fee_cost_net', function() {  
            updateTotal();
        });
        var updateTotal = function () {
          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var total = addit_fees;
            if(isNaN(total)){
            total=0.00;
            }
        output_total.val(total.toFixed(2));
        };          

        $j(document).on('change','#addit_taxable_flag', function() { 
    if($j(this).is(":checked")) {   

        var updateTotal = function () {

            updateTotal();

          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total_inc_vat = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var tax = parseFloat($j('#tax_id').val());

        var total_inc_vat = addit_fees * (tax + 1);
            if(isNaN(total_inc_vat)){
            total_inc_vat=0.00;
            }
        output_total_inc_vat.val(total_inc_vat.toFixed(2));
        };
    } else {
        var updateTotal = function () {

            updateTotal();

          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var total = addit_fees;
            if(isNaN(total)){
            total=0.00;
            }
        output_total.val(total.toFixed(2));
        };  
    }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as no matter how i try to format this i cannot get it to run i have just tried the below format but nothing fires. Many thanks in advance

```
    function updateTotal1(checked){
        if(checked == true){

        var updateTotal1 = function () {

            updateTotal1();

          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total_inc_vat = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var tax = parseFloat($j('#tax_id').val());

        var total_inc_vat = addit_fees * (tax + 1);
            if(isNaN(total_inc_vat)){
            total_inc_vat=0.00;
            }
        output_total_inc_vat.val(total_inc_vat.toFixed(2));
        };
    } else {

        var updateTotal1 = function () {

            updateTotal1();

          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var total = addit_fees;
            if(isNaN(total)){
            total=0.00;
            }
        output_total.val(total.toFixed(2));
    };
    };
    };
});

    $j('#addit_taxable_flag').on('change', function(){
         updateTotal($j(this).is(':checked'));
    });
```

Comment: define the appropriate `function updateTotal()` outside of `event` handler code. Or simply avoid using any other helper function and write you calculation logic there itself.

Comment: Did you define `updateTotal()` ? + what value is stored in updateTotal var ? the function does not return anythng

Comment: I have posted the full code above instead of just the part i was having issues with. as far as i can see update total was defined outide of the handler

Comment: Just to confirm the code works perfectly when i remove the if and the else so i can add either the top or bottom option it just wont work together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a large struggle and some outside help i have managed to resolve the issue. Many thanks for all of your help. apologies here is the code.

```
$j(function() {

        $j(document).on('keyup', '#addit_fee_cost_net', function() {  
            updateTotal();
        });
        var updateTotal = function () {
          addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');
        var tax = parseFloat($j('#tax_id').val());

        var total = addit_fees;
            if(isNaN(total)){
            total=0.00;
            }
            if($j('#addit_taxable_flag').is(":checked")) {
        var total = addit_fees * (tax + 1);
            }
        output_total.val(total.toFixed(2));
        };          

        $j(document).on('change','#addit_taxable_flag', function() {
            if($j(this).is(":checked")) {   
                    updateTotal2();
            } else {
                    updateTotal3();
            }
        });

    var updateTotal2 = function () {
        addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total_inc_vat = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var tax = parseFloat($j('#tax_id').val());

        var total_inc_vat = addit_fees * (tax + 1);
        if(isNaN(total_inc_vat)){
            total_inc_vat=0.00;
        }
        output_total_inc_vat.val(total_inc_vat.toFixed(2));
    };
    var updateTotal3 = function () {
        addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());

        var output_total = $j('#addit_fee_cost_gross');

        var total = addit_fees;
        if(isNaN(total)){
            total=0.00;
        }
        output_total.val(total.toFixed(2));
    };  

});
```

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question, but please consider expaining what you did to resolve it. Otherwise, this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

updateTotal() was called before being defined as function. you should put it after  the var updateTotal = function(){ ... } . Or,  I would simply just directly perform the logic you have .

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the function when it stored in a variable before defining the variable! `updateTotal is undefined` error should popup in your console.

```
$j(document).on('keyup', '#addit_fee_cost_net', function() {  
    updateTotal();//undefined
});
var updateTotal = function () {
  addit_fees = parseFloat($j('#addit_fee_cost_net').val());
```

First define your variable with the function in it and then call it.

```
var x = function () {};
x();
```

Comment: So do i only need do define the function once around the whole query or do i need to define it for each section

Comment: @troggy69 It is advisable to make a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

Before $(document).ready({...}) define your function because you need to define your functions before the "function **caller** or **trigger** loads".

```
function updateTotal(status){
 if(status == true){
  // if checked
 }
 else {
  // if not checked
 }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$j('#addit_taxable_flag').on('change', function(){
 updateTotal($j(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: Can i ask a favour and ask if someone could add this into my code i have edited with the answers above and either get the same error or the functions dont run at all. many thanks in advance for all help and answers that have been offered and apologies for my experience level :)

Comment: Did you change the selector name?

Comment: i havent changed anything it is a straight copy from the page